# Scala Play get response headers in Filter Middleware?

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to capture the response headers that my server is going to send with response headers to the browser. Upon inspection, I can see those:
[image]

However when I try to tap into those using my Filter Middleware:

```
class CustomFilter @Inject()(implicit val mat: Materializer, ec: ExecutionContext) extends Filter {
  private val logger = Logger(this.getClass)

  private def getRequestContext(ctx: RequestContext):String = {
    val RequestContext(userAgent, remoteAddress) = ctx
    // Log request context information based on availability of remoteAddress, appToken and appVersion
    s"NRS Request [User-Agent=$userAgent] [Remote-Address=$remoteAddress]"
  }

  private def getResponseContext(resCtx: ResponseContext): String = {
    val ResponseContext(duration, statusCode, appToken, appVersion, requestID, clientID, redirect, via) = resCtx
    s"NRS Response [DurationInMs=$duration] [Status=$statusCode] [App-Token=$appToken] [App-Version=$appVersion] [Request-ID=$requestID] [Client-ID=$clientID] [Redirect=$redirect] [Via=$via]"
  }


  private def getCompleteContext(reqCtx: RequestContext, resCtx: ResponseContext):String =
    s"{{${getRequestContext(reqCtx)}::${getResponseContext(resCtx)}}}"

  override def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result])(requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

    // Extract request context information
    val userAgent = requestHeader.headers.get("User-Agent").getOrElse("")
    val remoteAddress = requestHeader.headers.get("Remote-Address")

    nextFilter(requestHeader).flatMap { result =>
      val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
      val duration = endTime - startTime
      val status = result.header.status
      val appToken = result.header.headers.get("X-App-Token")
      val appVersion = result.header.headers.get("X-App-Version")
      val requestID = result.header.headers.get("X-Request-ID")
      val clientID = result.header.headers.get("X-Client-ID")
      val redirect = result.header.headers.get("X-Redirect")
      val via = result.header.headers.get("Via")

      println(s"""Headers: ${result.header.headers.mkString(",")}::${requestHeader.headers.headers.mkString(",")}""")

      if (userAgent.nonEmpty) {
        logger.warn(
          getCompleteContext(
            RequestContext(userAgent, remoteAddress),
            ResponseContext(duration, status, appToken, appVersion, requestID, clientID, redirect, via)
          )
        )
      }

      Future.successful(result)
    } recoverWith {
      case e: Throwable =>
        val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val duration = endTime - startTime

        if (userAgent.nonEmpty) {
          logger.warn(getCompleteContext(RequestContext(userAgent, remoteAddress), ResponseContext(duration, 500, None, None, None, None, None, None)))
        }

        // Propagate the exception
        Future.failed(e)
    }
  }
}
```

I am not able to see those response headers in my middleware, unfortunately. Can someone help me understand what am I doing wrong?

I am able to set new headers but not getting old headers:
`Future.successful(result.withHeaders("X-Request-ID-022" -> requestID.getOrElse("dvcsdf")))`

I get these response logs:

```
Response Header 121 - Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Response Header 121 - ETag: "XXXXXXX"
```

Here are the common Filters that I have applied:

```
class Filters @Inject()(corsFilter: CORSFilter,
                        clientIdFilter: ClientIdFilter,
                        requestIdFilter: RequestIdFilter,
                        processingTimeFilter: ProcessingTimeFilter,
                        host: HostFilter,
                        date: DateFilter,
                        head: HeadFilter,
                        gzipFilter: GzipFilter,
                        customFilter: CustomFilter
                       )
  extends DefaultHttpFilters(Seq(corsFilter, processingTimeFilter,
      clientIdFilter, requestIdFilter, host, date, head, gzipFilter,customFilter):_*)
```

Comment: Who is setting these `X-` headers? Your app code? Or another layer?

Comment: Another Layer actually. Similar to what I wrote there are multiple such filters that add these headers. I wanted to inspect my response at end of all these headers are done adding and then get those headers and log them

Comment: Ok so it's still in your app code, not something on top of your app. Then how are the filters declared? Are they in right order?

Comment: Orderwise my filter is at the end. Those are filters from external dependencies so I can't change that part of the code. I expected my filter to execute at the end when those headers are added but it seems it's still not getting those headers.

I think the easiest way would be to copy that implementation to obtain that part in this Filter. I have updated answer to show the filter combinator

Comment: If I read it correctly your filter is the "last" which means it's the last to be applied for requests but the first for responses. You might want to change that order.

Comment: Okay I see, but how do you conclude to that? If its last for requests it should also be last for responses right? Can you share a snippet in answer explaining the same? That would be extremely helpful

Comment: You can see it in your implementation: you do some logic on the request, you call `nextFilter` that does all its logic on the request/response, you do some logic on the response. Think russian doll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter needs to be at the start of the list. The code that applies the filters wraps them in the same order as the list, so basically expands out to this:

```scala
firstFilter.apply(secondFilter.apply(thirdFilter.apply(action))))
```

So, the first filter is the outer most filter, so when it gets a response back, it will get it from all the inner filters with the headers set by all the inner filters.